# How to make a shortcut for a program that doesn't showup in search results W8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-search, file-search

I noticed I have BitTorrent on my system. I wanted to make a shortcut for it on my desktop and/or metro-screen. However I don't know where it's located on my C drive. I "search" for bittorrent and all manner of related words and nothing comes up in windows search. Atm I only know how to open bittorrent by opening a torrent file. The program shows up in the install/uninstall list.

I see the solutions falling into:

1. If I could find the directory I could make the shortcut. What 'should' I be doing to find where this file exists in this situation? I browsed my programs list and couldn't find any word related to torrent. I don't see any gui feature in the program that tells me the directory where its located.
2. Is there a way to make the shortcut without knowing the file location ahead of time?

Comment: "I noticed I have BitTorrent on my system." Where did you notice this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get BitTorrent to launch by double-clicking on a torrent file, you can then look in Task Manager. Find the BitTorrent.exe process (it might be named differently, but there should only be a few dozen to look through on the Processes tab), and then right-click and select `Open File Location`. That will tell you where the executable is.

Comment: That did it. It was in the weirdest place...never woulda found it just by manually searching.

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed some bittorrent variant that is not called "bittorrent".

The original bittorrent client is installed here:

```
C:\Program Files\BitTorrent\bittorrent.exe
```

If that's not the one you have installed, see the list of
[BitTorrent Software Implementations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/The_World_of_Peer-to-Peer_%28P2P%29/Networks_and_Protocols/BitTorrent#Software_Implementations)
to jog your memory.